# Add image as a header in XWPF document

Tags: java, xwpf

How do I add a image as a header to every page in XWPF document ?
I have tried every possible thing I could think of , below is my code :

```
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
        CTSectPr sectPr = docx.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docx, sectPr);
        XWPFHeader header = policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST);
        String imgFile="sample.png";
        header.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        String nameoffile ="customer"+".docx";       
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(nameoffile);
        docx.write(out);
        out.close();
```

However this is giving me a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at line java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

You should add a correct directory for image. Probably "new FileInputStream(imgFile)" is null.
Put your image in directory then set path as:

```
String imgFile="C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\Project\sample.png";
```